# Global/static variables for MVC site config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, global-variables

whats the most efficient way to access global variables in MVC across multiple sessions?

I want access to possibly cached database data *for every user*, CompanyName, Amount of items on listing pages etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've created a settings service, and have used IoC (eg [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)) to instantiate it as a singleton. This provides more flexibility than just using the `web.config` AppSettings.

Comment: Can anybody confirm this is the best way of sharing/accessing variables globally across sessions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Note that I wouldn't implement the singleton manually - I'd use IoC to maintain that. That means the settings service just has to focus on getting and maintaining the required settings.

Comment: I've used [ServiceStack Caching](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) for caching the business objects - this would provide the amount of items on listing pages, etc.